# Remove Credentials from GIT in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

Anybody knows how to remove the users from the Credentials drop down in Jenkins for a project under Source Code Management -> Git Repositories

Referring to the section highlighted in yellow in attached screen shot: [image]

I seem to have added a few users in error and want to remove them from the drop down. I dont see any option to delete them.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Ok i found it, just had to look around. It was under the Jenkins Home page -> Credentials.

It is not present under the Credentials section of the Configuration page. I thought since it was GIT based, it was storing users under that configuration.

Comment: Yes, right there on the home page.  Not in the _Credentials_ section of the _Configuration_ page.

Comment: this didn't work for me.  the credentials I am trying to delete did not appear.

Comment: @ewok Try to go to your profile page and then click on Credentials on the right left menu

Answer (score 17):

**Detail Steps to delete GitHub's credentials from Jenkins:**

1. Go to **Jenkins's Dashboard**
2. Click on "**Credentials**" [Located at left side menu]
3. You will now able to see :

   - **Store**
   - **Domain**
   - **ID**
   - **Name**
4. Click on on "**Name**", you will get options "**Update**", "**Delete**" & "**Move**". **Choose your option.!**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Updated Location `18-Apr-2021`

`Dashboard` > `Manage Jenkins` > `Manage Credentials`

[image]

Comment: Mine still only works with the credentials link on the left.  Maybe I'm on an old version?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Dashboard> Manage jenkins> Credentials (in "Security" portion)

Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERbUk.png)

Comment: This seems to be the same as the Accepted Answer. FYI - you can choose Edit to suggest edits to that post, and will get reputation for that if they are accepted.